# Страница высотой в доступную область

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Имеем "тяжелую" страницу, состоящую с множества блоков. В основе лежат три блока, три дива. Размер сумы высоты этих блоков должен быть равен высоте видимой области.

Суть в том, что два верхних блока должны иметь фиксированную высоту, а 3 блок должен расширяться на доступную видимую часть экрана. В случае если в 3 блоке контент больше, чем высота, скролл должен быть на 3 блоке, а не общий для всех. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как такое сделать на css?

Comment: какие браузеры нужно поддерживать?

Comment: Обернуть в родительский див с min-height: 100%, всем родителям этого дива height: 100%.
  
Если по каким-то причинам такое невозможно, то первые два fixed/absolute, а третьему тот же min-height или даже height в 100% + padding-top в высоту первых двух блоков.

Comment: забыл сказать про браузеры, нужно поддерживать ie 8

Comment: Etki, спасибо, походу ваш способ только и возможен, жаль, что он не особо чист выходит. Ну да за поддержку ие 8 надо платить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
html, head {
    height: 100%;
}
div {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Как-то так

UPD. [Можно так](http://jsfiddle.net/wenL2rza/)

Comment: тогда body будет иметь скролл, потому что третий див на всю высоту, а первые два имеют фиксированную, таким образом, высота скрола будет равна высоте первых двух блоков и при перемотке в самый низ будет их (первые два дива) скрывать.

Comment: @include Обновил ответ. Можно еще через calc высоту считать, чтобы без абсолютов обойтись. Тогда будет

    height: calc(100% - 70px); // 70 - общая сумма высот двух блоков

Comment: увы ie 8 не тащит

Comment: @include если calc, то да. А то что на jsfiddle - не знаю. По идее, должно)